# Create an API to access google spreadsheet

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to make a google spreadsheet available to a remote user. This user wants to use API requests to access the spreadsheet. What is the best way to implement?
Using Web app or using Execution API?

Comment: accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

If the spreadsheet is not [protected](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection), you can easily access it using Spreadsheet's [openById](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById(String)).

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("abc1234567");
 Logger.log(ss.getName());
```